# Need help solving the Formal Language for: $L=\{w\in\{a,b\}∗ | \#ab(w) = \#ba(w) \}$

Tags: formal-languages

I've been trying create a formal language for the following  $L=\{w\in\{a,b\}∗ | \#ab(w) = \#ba(w) \}$.

First I've tried to do the following:

$S \to abSba | baSab | A | B| \mathcal E$

$A \to aA | Bb$

$B \to Ca$

$C \to \mathcal E$

But that solution isn't good as for example while I can output "$abbbbba$", but the opposite "$abaaaaaba$" is not possible.

And if I'll more variables for adding a's from the right the whole thing will become a complete mass.

I would be really glad to know where I'm doing wrong towards solving it and how should I approach in order to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following grammar that accepts words over the alphabet $ \{a,b\}^{*}$ that have an equal number of sequence of $ab$ as of $ba$. 
(Examples of words accepted are $\epsilon, aba, bab, aaa, bbabbb, abaabaaa$)

$ S \rightarrow a A_0 \ |\ b B_0 \ |\ \epsilon $

$ A_0 \rightarrow a A_0\ |\ bA_1 \ |\ \epsilon $

$ B_0 \rightarrow b B_0\ |\ aB_1 \ |\ \epsilon $

$ A_1 \rightarrow b A_1\ |\ a A_0  $

$ B_1 \rightarrow a B_1\ |\ b B_0  $

When you're in state $A_0$ you can add $a$'s (doesn't change the amount of $ab$ or $ba$) and you can finish your word at any moment. If you choose to add another $b$, i.e., increasing the sequence $ab$ by one you go to state $A_1$ in which you will have eventually to add one $a$.

Comment: I think there's mistake in your answer.
at B0, there should be bB0 and not bA0 as the all point that you can write limitless b's and finish at any moment.

Comment: you're write! It was a copy paste typo... I have edited it